# iOS 5.1 Drag&Drop from text view to table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I've developing an ipad app and i have been wondering if it's possible to select a text from a text view and by drag and dropping paste it into a uitableview.
If so can someone tell a bit so i can start working on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that might work is to use touch events and detect when you are dragging the textview and if so, put the text inside the textview into a private property and then detect when the dragging ends and see if you are in the area of the tableview (you would need to know the boundaries of the tableview (CGRect).  If you are in that area, you could then add the text to whatever datasource you have that populates that tableview and then reload the tableview.

This would take lots of trial and error to make sure the touch locations are right.

Comment: yes, i think so too. Thank you!